# Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Hashable'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to iterate trough my State `@State var items: [[Any]] = []`, It contains arrays that each contain an Object and a Date. I get the error of `Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Hashable'`

```
ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in                                  
BoughtImageItem(item: item[0] as! FeedPost, unlockDate: item[1] as! Date)
}
```

FeedPost looks like this:

```
struct FeedPost: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var timestamp: Date
    var description: String
    var locked: Bool?
    var likesCount: Int
    var price: Int
    var commentsCount: Int?
    var unlockLimit: Int?
    var unlockCount: Int?
    var images: [String]?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `[Any]`, use an actual object with properties for the post and date:

```swift
struct Item: Hashable {
    let post: FeedPost
    let date: Date
}

ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in                                  
    BoughtImageItem(item: item.post, unlockDate: item.date)
}
```

Comment: So my State would look like this: `@State var items: [[Item]]`, right? And for that I need `FeedPost` to conform to Equatable and make `Item` itself also conform to Hashable

Comment: It would be `@State var items: [Item]`.  `Item` needs to conform to Hashable, yes.  `FeedPost` already conforms to Equatable via its conformance to Hashable

Comment: What is the reason I cannot use Any?