# SwiftUI looping through an array of Any using a ForEach - Type 'any ' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've created a protocol as follows:

```
protocol InputViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID { get }
    var title: String { get }
    var shouldShowTitle: Bool { get }
    var data: String { get set }
    var placeholder: String { get }
    var fieldType: FieldType { get }
}
```

Using this protocol, I've created types like `TextFieldViewModel`, `TextViewViewModel`, `DatePickerViewModel` etc

In my SwiftUI view, I have a list which could have any input type so I have an array as follows:

`private(set) var inputViewModels: [any InputViewModel] = []`

I populate this with required view models.

Now in my SwiftUI view, I want to loop through these view models and build the UI so I do this:

```
List {
    ForEach(currentProjectViewModel.projectInfoViewModels) { inputViewModel in
        if let inputViewModel = inputViewModel as? TextFieldRowViewModel {
            createUI(inputViewModel: inputViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I get the error `Type 'any InputViewModel' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'`

[image: SwiftUI error looping to any type]

I know one way to fix this would be to make the `inputViewModels` of a specific type so that would be `private(set) var inputViewModels: [InputViewModel] = []` without the use of `any`, however, I do have the requirement to support any input type.

Another solution would be to use `indices` as follows

```
ForEach(currentProjectViewModel.projectInfoViewModels.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    let viewModel = currentProjectViewModel.projectInfoViewModels[index]
    
    if let inputViewModel = viewModel as? TextFieldRowViewModel {
        createUI(inputViewModel: inputViewModel)
    }
}
```

However, I've heard that using indices is not really reliable in SwiftUI views and as much as possible we want to iterate over the object

I also came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883670/protocol-any-as-a-type-cannot-conform-to-hashable) but it is similar to the first solution I pointed out here.

How could I achieve what I want in the simplest / cleanest way possible ?

Comment: You should not have an array of these "view models" in the first place. SwiftUI views *are* the view models. Writing your own view models would be over-engineering. Just keep an array of the *data* these views are operating on, and `ForEach` over that data instead. That data can include a property that indicates whether it is a text field, text view, or date picker, and you can check that with a `switch` inside the `ForEach`, and produce different views.

Comment: Instead of self use id like that answer but eventually you will need to cast to the concrete types

Comment: By the way, using indices as id is reliable. The idea of an `id` is they don't change for the "same" object, whatever "same" means. If you are not reordering the array or adding/removing elements, the ids don't change and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

`protocol InputViewModel` is a bad idea because there is already the `protocol View` for the view model.

`ForEach` with `indices` and `id: \.self` will crash when you access `[index]` if the array changes. It's not a loop, you need to supply a valid `id` or supply an array of data conforming to `Identifiable`.